# remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using git-lab.
I am facing an error while using `git pull/push/clone` command:

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://gitlab.com/myname/myproject'

I am facing this problem after `git config --global --unset credential.helper`.

Can anyone help me to come out of this problem?

Do I need to do any proxy settings? (is this firewall related issue?)

I am struct and I am not able to get working solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally works after resetting the username & password in windows credential manager.
thanks

Answer (score 5):

I tried many solutions listed in other similar questions , including the one mentioned above but it did not work me. what did work for me is the below way.

- Go to your project directory and find for .git folder which will **hidden** by default.
- Enter that and find for a **config** file and open with text editor and make changes to its **token** in the URL key something like below

[remote "origin"]

```
url = https://gitlab-ci-token:<token>@<repository-URL>
```

In my  case the token had expired which one can easily generate in the settings -> Access token->Create a token.

Copy paste this token to your config file in .git folder and Restart your IDE for changes to reflect.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 4):

First of all open CMD as administrator (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) then insert this

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Then you will type you username and password. Thats all.

Comment: Thx, that's the one that helped me, however, it worked with --global instead of --system.

Comment: yes I confirm
with 

git config --system --unset credential.helper

I obtain
error: could not lock config file /etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

with

git config --global --unset credential.helper

it's ok

Comment: @936940 that is because you are not running it as an admin.